# Jekyll HTML Page Not Rendering Liquid

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

I'm currently using jekyll to build a static site and it appears that the HTML files are not parsing liquid.

My current directory structure looks like

```
_layouts
  page.html
index.html
```

index.html:

```
---
layout: page
title: home
---

{{ foo }}
```

When I visit `http://host/index.html`, the layout is applied as expected but the page doesn't evaluate `{{ foo }}` but instead prints the string `{{ foo }}`.

Comment: Just to be sure, you're visiting the url through jekyll server right?

Comment: Yes, I'm accessing it at http://localhost:4000/index.html also, wouldn't this not make a difference since its going to output HTML anyways?

Comment: I have this happening with html files, but md files work just fine. The "Step-by-Step Tutorial" fails on step 2 for me because of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't show us where and how you defined `foo`.

There are several possible ways how to do that...and for each one, the syntax to display the value is slightly different:

---

### In [_config.yml](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/):

Declaration:

```
foo: whatever
```

To display it on the page:

```
{{ site.foo }}
```

---

### In the [front-matter](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/) of the same page:

Declaration:

```
---
foo: whatever
---
```

To display it on the page:

```
{{ page.foo }}
```

---

### In the body of the same page *(e.g., **not** in the front-matter)*:

Declaration:

```
{% assign foo = 'whatever' %}
```

To display it on the page:

```
{{ foo }}
```

Comment: If foo is not defined it does not print the "{{ foo }}" to the page and it's just totally blank. The OP asked why does the "{{ foo }}" appear in it's literal form on the page? Defining foo is not the issue. I have the same problem right now doing the Step-by-Step tutorial and it doesn't work for a fresh install for html pages. Works fine for md. I suspect a missing config option that turns liquid on for html pages.

Comment: Maybe that changed in the 8 years since I wrote that answer, I don't remember.
IMO the OP actually asks why Jekyll doesn't render the value of `foo` correctly (quotes: "HTML Page Not Rendering Liquid", "but the page doesn't evaluate `{{ foo }}`").